# Where my logic went wrong while solving this probability problem from Sheldon Ross' book?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I was solving following problem from the book "A first course in probability" by Sheldon Ross

> A group of 6 men and 6 women is randomly divided into 2 groups of size 6 each. What is the probability that both groups will have the same number of men?

I solved it as follows:

> It was clear to me that this division can be done in $\binom{6}{3}\times\binom{6}{3}$ ways. However I was a bit confused of denominator against which probability is to be calculated, that is, how many number of ways are there to divide 12 people into two groups. I thought it as follows:
>
> - One group contains all men, other group contains all women. This can be done in only $1$ way.
> - One group contains 1 man and 5 women, and the other group contains all remaining (5 men and 1 woman). This can be done in $\binom{6}{1}\times\binom{6}{5}$ ways.
> - One group contains 2 men and 4 women, and the other group contains all remaining (4 men and 2 women). This can be done in $\binom{6}{2}\times\binom{6}{4}$ ways.
> - One group contains 3 men and 3 women, and the other group contains all remaining (3 women and 3 men). This can be done in $\binom{6}{3}\times\binom{6}{3}$ ways.
>     So I felt that the final probability would be $\frac{\binom{6}{3}\binom{6}{3}}{1+\binom{6}{1}\binom{6}{5}+\binom{6}{2}\binom{6}{4}+\binom{6}{3}\binom{6}{3}}=\frac{400}{662}\approx 0.6042$

But the answer given in the book is $0.4329$ which is apparently calculated as (I realised this when I googled) $$\frac{\binom{6}{3}\binom{6}{3}}{\frac{12!}{6!6!}}=\frac{400}{924}$$

**My doubts**

1. Where did I made mistake in my logic while forming sample space of 662?
2. Somehow, I still feel mine is correct. Is it so?

**Some update**

I tried forming sample space for smaller number of people: 2 men and 2 women divided in 2 groups of 2 people each:

By books formula, it will be $\frac{4!}{2!2!}=6$, which can me cross checked as follows:

```
m1 m2 w1 w2    Two groups     Division ID
-----------  --------------   -----------
g1 g1 g2 g2  {m1,m2}{w1,w2}       D1
g1 g2 g1 g2  {m1,w1}{m2,w2}       D2
g1 g2 g2 g1  {m1,w1}{m2,w1}       D3
g2 g2 g1 g1  {w1,w2}{m1,m2}       D4
g2 g1 g2 g1  {m2,w2}{m1,w1}       D5    
g2 g1 g1 g2  {m2,w1}{m1,w2}       D6
```

By my logic, it would have been $\binom{2}{1}\binom{2}{1}+\binom{2}{2}\binom{2}{0} = 4+1=5$. When I compared this to above table, I realised that my logic considers divisions `D1` and `D6` as same and I felt that its essentially correct as these divisions simply forms one group of all men and other group of all women. Books logic is counting them twice by once calling men's group as "group 1" and women's group as "group 2" and then again by calling men's group as "group 2" and women's group as "group 1". However both divisions are same. However, then I felt that

- `D2` and `D5` are also same
  Both groups `m1` and `w1` together and `m2` and `w2` together
- `D3` and `D6` are also same
  Both groups `m1` and `w2` together and `m2` and `w1` together

So total distinct divisions would have been just 3. That means even my logic would have been wrong!!!

Whats going wrong? Am I thinking unnecessarily too much?

Comment: There is a symmetry in the $(3,3)$ case that isn't present in any other case.  That complicates matters.  To get equiprobable events, it is easiest to consider ordered pairs instead of unordered pairs (as you are, partially, doing).

Comment: I tried doing same for 2 men and 2 women which I have added at the end of original question. Can you please explain where did I go wrong in that? I mean what divisions I missed there?

Comment: The same problem arises in working with dice.  If you say that $(1,2)$ is the same as $(2,1)$, hence if you are working with unordered pairs, then you have to deal with the symmetry problem.  In this case, the unordered pair $\{1,1\}$ is only half as likely as the unordered pair $\{1,2\}$.  Much better to work with ordered pairs.

Comment: Using ordered pairs;  your numerator is correct as you must choose $3$ men and $3$ women to play for team $A$.  Your denominator, however, neglects the fact that team $A$ might contain $4,5$ or $6$ men.  You think you covered that by symmetry, but you didn't.

Comment: Ok, so one precise question. Ordered pair counts divisions `D2:{m1,w1}{m2,w2}}` and `D5:{m2,w2}{m1,w1}` as two separate divisions. Should these two divisions be counted separately? Or is same division since both group same man and woman in same group?

Comment: I'm not sure of your notation.  Sticking with mine, Teams $A$ and $B$, then it is very different if you have team $A$ $=(m_1,w_1)$ or $=(m_2,w_2)$.  The "ordering" I refer to is between the two Teams, not within a single team.

Comment: N F Taussing's [(earlier / non edited) answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2814769/revisions) asked to divide both numerator and denominator by $\frac{1}{2}$ to highlight that those divisions (D1 and D2) are same  and it still achieves same final probability. What do you say about this? This is what he did: $\frac{\dfrac{1}{2}\dbinom{6}{3}\dbinom{6}{3}}{\dfrac{1}{2}\dbinom{12}{6}} = \frac{\dbinom{6}{3}\dbinom{6}{3}}{\dbinom{12}{6}}=\frac{400}{924}$. Please tell if am correct in [this comment on his answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2814725#comment5804014_2814769).

Comment: That's a clever approach.  By removing one man, the writer removes the $3,3$ case which means that you can go back to using unordered pairs.  Looks entirely correct to me.  Personally, I think the method I sketched (using ordered pairs) is more universally applicable, but it's good to learn all sorts of devices.

Comment: I took my time on this problem and I definitively conclude that you are not thinking at all too much. As you see, the number 12 is not mentioned in the problem, but it is there, present in the answer, whose author presumably false assumed that all of us understand that 6 + 6 = 12. The right way to do it is to work with numbers smaller than 6 + 1, like you did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> One group contains $3$ men and $3$ women and the other group contains all remaining ($3$ women and $3$ men).  This can be done in $\binom{6}{3}\binom{6}{3}$ ways.

This claim is true if the groups are *labeled*.  For instance, if one group is assigned to do computer programming and the other is assigned to software testing, then it matters which person is in which group.  Under that assumption, there are $\binom{12}{6}$ ways to select the two groups since it matters which six people are placed in the computer programming group.  Under this assumption, your sample space was too small since you did not take into account the possibilities that there are more men than women in the group you are selecting.  The number of ways of selecting exactly $\color{blue}{k}$ men and $\color{red}{6 - k}$ women for the computer programming group is $$\color{blue}{\binom{6}{k}}\color{red}{\binom{6}{6 - k}}$$
so the number of ways of selecting the computer programming group is 
$$\color{blue}{\binom{6}{0}}\color{red}{\binom{6}{6}} + \color{blue}{\binom{6}{1}}\color{red}{\binom{6}{5}} + \color{blue}{\binom{6}{2}}\color{red}{\binom{6}{4}} + \color{blue}{\binom{6}{3}}\color{red}{\binom{6}{3}} + \color{blue}{\binom{6}{4}}\color{red}{\binom{6}{2}} + \color{blue}{\binom{6}{5}}\color{red}{\binom{6}{1}} + \color{blue}{\binom{6}{6}}\color{red}{\binom{6}{0}} = \binom{12}{6}$$
Then the probability that both groups have the same number of men is 
$$\frac{\dbinom{6}{3}\dbinom{6}{3}}{\dbinom{12}{6}}$$

However, the assumption that the groups are labeled is not necessary.  But we need to be careful when we divide a group of $12$ people into two groups of six people.  Choosing six of the $12$ people to be in one group means the other six people are in the other group.  Hence, we get the same two groups when we pick a particular group of people and when we pick its complement.  Thus, in selecting six of twelve people to be in one group, we count every division into two groups of six twice.  Therefore, the number of ways of dividing twelve people into two groups of six is 
$$\frac{1}{2}\binom{12}{6}$$
and the number of ways of selecting three men and three women to be in one group is 
$$\frac{1}{2}\binom{6}{3}\binom{6}{3}$$
so the probability that each group contains the same number of men is 
$$\frac{\dfrac{1}{2}\dbinom{6}{3}\dbinom{6}{3}}{\dfrac{1}{2}\dbinom{12}{6}} = \frac{\dbinom{6}{3}\dbinom{6}{3}}{\dbinom{12}{6}}$$

**Alternate Solution:**  Suppose that Alexander is one of the men.  He must be in one of the two groups.  There are $\binom{11}{5}$ ways to select five of the other eleven people to be in his group.  In a favorable case, two of the other five men and three of the six women must be in his group.  The number of such selections is $\binom{5}{2}\binom{6}{3}$.  Hence, the probability that both groups will have the same number of men is 
$$\frac{\dbinom{5}{2}\dbinom{6}{3}}{\dbinom{11}{5}}$$

Comment: Why did you just deleted the first solution? I felt it was only correct answer here. I feel, it was the only answer here that says division d1={group1={m1,m2,m3,w1,w2,w3},group2={m4,m5,m6,w4,w5,w6}} is same as division d2={group1={m4,m5,m6,w4,w5,w6},group2={m1,m2,m3,w1,w2,w3}}. They simply gives different numbers to groups. You highlighted this in deleted answer by dividing both numerator and denominator by 2 and still got the same answer. I felt its the most logically correct approach. Other answers ask to follow ordered division. But I feel its wrong. Correct?

Comment: I dont know whether I should be surprised to find that the probabilities are same in both cases: groups are labeled vs group are unlabeled. Is it by chance that both probabilities are same? Also I guess question does not mean to say groups are distinguishable. So now I was confused, why you have considered distinguishable groups (is it for sake of completeness of answer or question does indeed means possibility of distinguishable groups) and what to do when such problem is asked in the exam...?

Comment: It is not a coincidence.  Whether the groups are labeled are not, they consist of the same groups of people.

Comment: My interpretation is that the groups are unlabeled.  I treated the question both ways for the sake of completeness.  Also, I wanted to show why you did not obtain either $\binom{12}{6}$ or $\frac{1}{2}\binom{12}{6}$ elements in your sample space.

Comment: The alternate solution is not a solution. When Alexander steps in any problem, he skews the distribution. Here, by chance, given the fact that $3.12=6^2$, the numbers happens to fit.

Answer (score 1):

You have considered the following cases:

- 6 men, 0 women
- 1 man, 5 women
- 2 men, 4 women
- 3 men, 3 women

You are missing the other three:

- 0 men, 6 women
- 4 men, 2 women
- 5 men, 1 woman

Update your denominator to
$$ \left[1 + \binom 6 1 \binom 6 5 + \binom 6 2 \binom 6 4 + \binom 6 3  \binom 6 3 \right] + \binom 6 4 \binom 6 2 + \binom 6 5 \binom 6 1 + 1$$
to get the correct answer.

I think your intuition is that there is something fundamentally similar about, say, 4 men and 2 women versus 2 men and 4 women. That is of course correct; the probabilities are the same, but nevertheless they are separate cases that (in this formulation) must be accounted for separately. In short, your sample space is indeed too small.

**EDITED TO ADD:** Perhaps the *real* crux of the confusion is the distinguishability of the groups. Generally, in probability you want to regard *all* things as distinguishable, even if it feels like they may not be distinguishable in practice.

As an example, if you roll two identical dice, they may not be "distinguishable" to your eye, but they are nevertheless different dice and must be treated as distinguishable when you do the calculation; this is why you fix one to be "Die A" and the other to be "Die B," even if in practice you would not be able to tell which was which after rolling them. The situation is similar here with the groups. Although there may be no meaningful distinction between them, imagine that one must stand on the left side of a room and the other on the right, or that one group is lucky and receives a prize, etc. Clearly, such matters can't actually affect the computation, and distinguishing between the groups helps you to avoid issues like the $\binom 6 3$ repetition articulated by others in this thread.

Comment: Point is are divisions (call D1) {G1: 4 men and 2 women, G2: 2 men and 4 women} and (call D2) {G1: 2 men and 4 women, G2: 4 men and 2 women} two different divisions? D1 simply calls {4 men and 2 women} as G1 while same is called G2 by D2. Similarly what D1 calls as G2 is called as G1 by D2. But the **"divisions"** are same, isnt it?

Comment: They're not, for the same reason this doesn't hold with dice; having "Die A" roll a 5 and "Die B" roll a 2 is different than swapping them around, even if you can't actually tell the dice apart. Imagine that the group on the left side of the room will win a prize; then having the "4 men" group win the prize is a different thing than having the "4 women" group win the prize.

Comment: N F Taussing's [(earlier / non edited) answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2814769/revisions) asked to divide both numerator and denominator by $\frac{1}{2}$ to highlight that those divisions (D1 and D2) are same  and it still achieves same final probability. What do you say about this? This is what he did: $\frac{\dfrac{1}{2}\dbinom{6}{3}\dbinom{6}{3}}{\dfrac{1}{2}\dbinom{12}{6}} = \frac{\dbinom{6}{3}\dbinom{6}{3}}{\dbinom{12}{6}}=\frac{400}{924}$. Please tell if am correct in [this comment on his answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2814725#comment5804014_2814769).

Comment: That other way is fine -- and notably, gives the right answer -- but to my mind, it's more convoluted. I think it's a bit harder to grasp the concept of why $\binom 6 3 \binom 6 3$ uniquely deserves a $\frac 1 2$ multiplier than to understand the concept of distinguishing between the groups. But, perhaps you find it easier to understand in that way.

Comment: Ok. Just want point that N F Taussig has very clearly mentioned that having just $\binom{6}{3}\binom{6}{3}$ in the numerator is completely wrong as it will count every such division twice, once when selecting a particular group of three men and three women and once when selecting its complement and hence it has to be $\frac{1}{2}\binom{6}{3}\binom{6}{3}$, which sounds factually correct. Thus I felt that any solution which uses only $\binom{6}{3}\binom{6}{3}$ in the numerator is simply logically wrong, even though it results in the same final probability.

Comment: I only briefly skimmed it and can't see it now, so perhaps it was wrong. It looked right to me at a brief glance.

Comment: It comes down to whether or not the groups are labeled.  If the groups are labeled, then the number of ways of dividing twelve people into two groups of six is $\binom{12}{6}$ and the number of favorable cases is $\binom{6}{3}$.  Your answer is correct for labeled groups.  If the groups are unlabeled, the number of ways of dividing twelve people into two groups of six is $\frac{1}{2}\binom{12}{6}$ and the number of favorable cases is $\frac{1}{2}\binom{6}{3}\binom{6}{3}$.  The two methods yield the same answer.

Answer (score 1):

What went wrong with your logic has been pointed out in two answers, so I shan't dwell on it.

Re the question of groups being labelled or unlabelled, please understand that # of ways hasn't been asked for, and since **probability** is a ratio, you will get the same answer under either of the assumptions, and you can **choose** the assumption that is simplest to compute.

So I **choose** to consider the groups as labelled, and compute$\quad Pr =\dfrac{\binom63\binom63}{\binom{12}6}$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have to board 12 people in two canoes.

Actually there are three problems here :

i) the indistinguishable canoes having the solution:

$$\frac{ \frac{1}{2}\binom{6}{3}\binom{6}{3}}{1+\binom{6}{1}\binom{6}{5}+\binom{6}{2}\binom{6}{4}+\frac{1}{2}\binom{6}{3}\binom{6}{3}}= \frac{200}{1+36+225+200}=\frac{200}{462}$$

ii) indistinguishable canoes with Alexander and other five men
  $$\frac{\binom{5}{2}\binom{6}{3}}{\binom{11}{5}}=\frac{200}{462}$$

iii) the distinguishable canoes : $$\frac{\binom{6}{3}\binom{6}{3}}{\binom{12}{6}}=\frac{400}{924}$$

If the twelve people were to be distributed in three unlabeled canoes, there are five partition types :

$0+2+4 \to \binom{6}{2} \binom{6}{2} = 15×15 $

$1+1+4 \to \frac{1}{2}\binom{6}{2} \binom{6}{3} = 15×20 $

$0+3+3 \to \frac{1}{2}\binom{6}{3} \binom{6}{1} \binom{5}{1}= 10×30 $

$1+2+3 \to \binom{6}{1} \binom{5}{2}\binom{6}{1} \binom{5}{2} = 60×60$

$2+2+2 \to \frac{1}{6}\binom{6}{2} \binom{4}{2}  \binom{2}{2}\binom{6}{2} \binom{4}{2}  \binom{2}{2}= 15×90 = 1350$

$$P_{unlabeled} = \frac {1350}{5775} = \frac{18}{77}  \approx 0.2337 $$

The labeled case is simpler :

$$P_{labeled} = \frac {\binom{6}{2} \binom{4}{2}  \binom{2}{2}\binom{6}{2} \binom{4}{2}  \binom{2}{2} }
{ \binom{12}{4}  \binom{8}{4}   \binom{4}{4} } = \frac{18}{77} \approx 0.2337   $$

Finally, I would like to add the species/e.g.f. approach:

$$ \frac {coeff \ 6,6} {coeff \ 6,6} \ \frac {(E_2[X]·E_2[Y])^3}{(E_4[X+Y])^3} \to \frac {8100}{34650} =  \frac {18}{77} $$
We have to divide the coefficients of $\frac {x^6y^6}{6!.6!}$ in the two egf's of the associated species.

Comment: As I have asked other, I want to ask the same to you.  N F Taussig has very clearly mentioned that having just $\binom{6}{3}\binom{6}{3}$ in the numerator is completely wrong as it will count every such division twice, once when selecting a particular group of three men and three women and once when selecting its complement and hence it has to be $\frac{1}{2}\binom{6}{3}\binom{6}{3}$, which sounds factually correct. Thus I felt that any solution which uses only $\binom{6}{3}\binom{6}{3}$ in the numerator is simply logically wrong, even though it results in the same final probability.

Comment: Actually, in the alternate approach, the answer is $\frac{\binom{5}{2}\binom{6}{3}}{\binom{11}{5}} = \frac{200}{462}$.

Comment: As has been pointed out by N.F. Taussig, the answer you give for indistinguishable canoes is incorrect. You may like to amend it in order to avoid confusion.

Comment: apologize, I have done it.